# Map instance not read as object instance

Tags: java, list, dictionary, generics, compiler-errors

I have this code:

```
List<Map<Object, Object>> list = new ArrayList<>();

list.add(new HashMap<>().put("key", "value"));
```

However it tells me this:

> add (java.util.Map) in List cannot
>   be applied to (java.lang.Object)

Why can't `add` function of list read the `Map` instance as an `Object` instance? But if it's a simple list it

```
List<Object> simpleList = new 
simpleList.add("
simpleList.add(new HashMap<>().put("sample","sample"));
```

*Edit*:

This also does not work:

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("key", "value");
list.add(map);
```

> add(java.util.Map) in List cannot
>   be applied to (java.util.Map)

*Edit 2*:

Thanks for your answers I understand now why it won't work. So what would be the best possible way to implement this? It is iterating in a loop because I'm adding multiple HashMaps to a List.

```
Map<Object, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
something.foreach{ thing ->{
if(map!=null)
map.clear();
map.put("key", thing);
list.add(map);
}
}
```

Is `map` mutable? Or is this bad code?

Comment: because `Map.put()` returnes the *value*, not the map itself.

Comment: Tried Map<Object, Object> on the last sample. It worked. Will try to investigate some cases for a while.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`HashMap.put()` returns just the value as an object so doing `new HashMap<>().put("key", "value");` does not return the hashmap but the value instead or null;

> **put** Returns:the previous value associated with key, or null if there was no mapping for key. (A null return can also indicate that the map previously associated null with key.)

You need to do

```
Map<Object, Object> item = new HashMap<>();
item.put("key", "value");

list.add(item);
```

Comment: Or `list.add(Map.of("key", "value"))` (assuming you don't care about subsequent mutability of the map).

Comment: 'put()' returns the value previously associated with the specified key. It does not return the key

Comment: What is this `Map.of`?

Comment: @RobertKock Fixed it in my post. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

The `put()` method within `HashMap` returns the value previously inserted in the map and not the object itself.

Edit:
You said that this doesn't work:

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("key", "value");
list.add(map);
```

That's because your list contains elements of type "Map of objects" and you're trying to insert a "Map of Strings"

Answer (score 2):

You are not putting an instance of `java.util.Map<java.lang.Object,java.lang.Object>` but rather the result of Hasmap.put which is the previous value associated with the key (in your case `null`) as stated by [Map#put](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#put-K-V-)'s javadoc

You simply need to do it in two steps :

```
Map<Object, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("key", "value")
list.add(map);
```

Or in one step (Fun but **not recommended** as this creates pointlessly a new anonymous class) :

```
list.add(new HashMap<Object, Object>() {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    {
         put("key", "value");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Because the put method

> Returns:
>
> the previous value associated with key, or null if there was no
>   mapping for key. (A null return can also indicate that the map
>   previously associated null with key.)

It returns the previous value and because your values are of type Object it returns an Object.

You cannot chain the Map creation and putting something into it together and have the Map returned.
You need to split it into multiple steps:

```
Map<Object, Object> myMap = new HashMap<>();
myMap.put("key", "value");
list.add(myMap);
```

Answer (score 2):

[`Map#put`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#put-K-V-) returns the value associated with the key before `put` was called (or `null` if there was no such value), not the `Map` itself.

If you want a oneliner to create a `Map`, you can consider [`Collections#singletonMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#singletonMap-K-V-):

```
list.add(new HashMap<>(Collections.singletonMap("key", "value")));
```

(or, just drop the call to `new HashMap` if you're OK with immutable maps)